# Thymeleaf sec:authorize and sec:authentication attributes, not take effect on production but working fine on IDE

Tags: linux, thymeleaf, production-environment

Good day, in my case everything is fine and working great on localhost ide, but on site under linux thymeleaf sec:authorize and sec:authentication attributes, not take effect.

```
   <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring5</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.11.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- marked the embedded servlet container as provided -->
```

And here is HTML

```
<li sec:authorize="isAnonymous()"><a class="inner-link" href="/login" title="Login">Login</a></li>
                            <li sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()"><a  class="inner-link" th:href="@{/profile}" title="Profile">Profile</a></li>
```

No error or warn on boot. Please advice

Comment: Do you have an overriding dependency In your prod environment? Maybe a conflict in jars. By the way what is your spring-boot version

Comment: By the way `<dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring5</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.11.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>` seems problematic to me. Are you sure this dependency is necessary?

Comment: This two help to run  sec:authorize and sec:authentication attributes on localhost```<dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring5</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.11.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>```

Comment: I dont have overriding dependency. I think somone that run java on linux shoud now witch version of thymeleaf and spring to use.

Comment: @Bobi I had the same problem. I defined `xmlns:sec="https://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5"` in my html and tried to get value from `sec:authentication="principal.fullname"` but I cannot show the value. I only show it via `[[${#request.userPrincipal.principal.fullName}]]`. How can I fix my issue?

Answer (score 0):

After 4 days of struggle I have run to boote local machine and on linux server
with this config:
pom.xml

```
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring5</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- marked the embedded servlet container as provided -->
```

It does not work with parent version 3 or upper and not working with v 1.5 and down. 
in  SecurityConfig i have added a bean

```
 @Bean
    public SpringSecurityDialect securityDialect() {
        return new SpringSecurityDialect();
    }
```

Thank you